# Remove join date

Tags: pypi

How do I remove the `Joined on MM DD, YYYY` from my PyPI public profile?
Clicking on "Edit profile" does not give me the option to hide it.

Most accounts have the `Joined on MM DD, YYYY`. New accounts show it by default.

---

Examples:

[tusharmakkar08](https://pypi.org/user/tusharmakkar08/) (4 projects) has `Joined on May 22, 2016`

but

[alecthomas](https://pypi.org/user/alecthomas/) (12 projects) does not have `Joined on MM DD, YYYY`.

From this I thought that if there are greater than 10 projects then the date is not shown.

---

Counterexample:

[iotile](https://pypi.org/user/iotile/) (30 projects) does not have `Joined on MM DD, YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like very old accounts don't have join date